# CSS generic styles VS specific styles - for efficiency

Tags: html, css

Basically I would like to know which of the following methods (giving the same results) is more efficient, and although it would be negligable with the size of the examples i'm giving I would like to assume the techniques over a full site for the answer.

Example 1

```
//generic
.round { border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; } //-o-, -ms-.....
.blue { color:blue; }
.red { color:red; }
//specific
.title { width:100px; height:20px; background:black; }
.image { width:50px; height:50px; }

<div class="title round blue">title</div>
<div class="image round red">image</div>
```

Example 2

```
//specific
.title { width:100px; height:20px; background:black; border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px;color:blue; }
.image { width:50px; height:50px; border-radius:5px; -moz-border-radius:5px; color:red;}

<div class="title">title</div>
<div class="image">image</div>
```

Any thoughts on this would be great!
Cheers

Comment: Totally depends on convenience ..

Comment: efficiency never depends on convenience! or are you stating there isn't any difference in efficiency, so choose the most convenient per project?

Comment: Do you compensate convenience of handling code with increasing the efficiency (In CSS) which hardly matters for normal websites? And yes, I choose convenience for my projects as they are not as huge as facebook and google so efficiency hardly matters

Comment: For things like this where there is little measurable impact on real-world performance, I would say that efficiency of coding and maintenance time is more important than efficency of the actual code. CSS Best practice is closer to your second example than your first; stick with that.

Comment: Also, the various different browsers may well process these things completely differently internally. The "most efficient" option may be different in different browsers. Moreover, even if you could say for certain that one option is better now, the browser makers may make changes to their code in the future that changes that. So the real answer is don't try to micro-optimise. Stick with recommended best practice (ie your second option), if for no other reason than because browser makers will try to target their optimisations for well-written code.

Comment: oh, and one other thing -- vendor prefixes really aren't required for `border-radius` any more... FF3.6 was the last browser that needed one.

Comment: It depends on opinion and preference. The first option resembles the "Object Oriented CSS" model that's being promoted by Nicole Sullivan. It actually has some merit, I think, at least in small doses.

Comment: I'd avoid the *efficiency* word as the comments suggest. To get proper answer and not let your question close, I'd suggest something like *in which situations is specific CSS preferred over generic?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no significant difference in the rendering of CSS methods. The consideration is really how long the CSS files take to download. Clearly, nice tightly written CSS will download faster than verbose CSS with too many declarations. However, if you are wanting to have (extending your example) many different styles of title then the more verbose method could be preferable because it will end up being "tighter" in the long run.

```
.title{font-size:18px;padding:20px 0;font-family:verdana}
.blue{color:#00f}
.red{color:#f00}
.bgyellow{background-color:#ff0}

<div class="title red">My Title</div>
<div class="title blue">My Title</div>
<div class="title bgyellow red">My Title</div>
```

Is preferable to...

```
.redtitle{font-size:18px;padding:20px 0;font-family:verdana;color:#f00}
.bluetitle{font-size:18px;padding:20px 0;font-family:verdana;color:#00f}
.redbgyellowtitle{font-size:18px;padding:20px 0;font-family:verdana;color:#f00;background-color:#ff0}

<div class="redtitle">My Title</div>
<div class="bluetitle">My Title</div>
<div class="redbgyellowtitle">My Title</div>
```

As you can see, the second example will start getting unwieldy, whereas the first will be more concise and easier to read when the going gets tough.

Having said that, if your styles are going to be all the same throughout the site (e.g. red, 18px verdana) then you should do this with a single declaration.

Don't flame me if my code above is buggy - it's off the top of my head without testing ;-)